# Context in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, android-context

I store information if user is logged in SharedPreferences.
In my ViewPager adapter I want to check if userIsLoggedIn. Depending on that I will display different fragments.
My question is: in order to get data from sharedPreferences I need a context. How do I get it from my ViewPager adapter class?
Thank you.

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public ViewPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragmentManager = fm;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0: return new FragmentInsta();
        case 1: return new FragmentList();
        case 2: return new FragmentHostUnlogged();
        default:
            return new FragmentList();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    if (object instanceof FragmentHostUnlogged)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) . <s>**FragmentPagerAdapter**</s> is deprecated.

```
class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

         Context context; 

         ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager,Context c) {
            super(manager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
            context=c;
        }
```

Read [**Context**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) from official guideline.

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system.

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
```